# Ruby write to file exception

Tags: ruby

I'm having some troubles with a Ruby script I wrote to unzip an archive and then make files.

```
script.rb:66: syntax error, unexpected unary+, expecting '}'
...images/pages/"+ filename.to_s +".jpg', alt=''"
```

```
@fileList.each do |filename|

    File.open('templates/layouts/_partials/page-' + filename.to_s + '.jade', 'w') { |file|
        file.puts ".c-page\n"
        file.puts "  img(src='images/pages/"+ filename.to_s +".jpg', alt=''"
    }
end
```

If I do this:

```
File.open('templates/layouts/_partials/page-' + filename.to_s + '.jade', 'w') { |file|
                file.puts ".c-page\n"
                file.puts "  img(src='images/pages/"
                file.puts filename.to_s 
                file.puts ".jpg', alt=''"
            }
```

I don't have the result I want, because it prints a new line every time.

Comment: try using string interpolation instead e.g. `file.puts "  img(src='images/pages/#{filename.to_s}.jpg', alt=''"`. Also puts appends a new line character so I am not sure you need to use the new line in the first `puts`

Comment: What class is `filename`? If it's a String, it's redundant to do `to_s` to it. `file.puts ".c-page\n"` is redundant since `puts` automatically adds a new-line if none is present. Instead simply use `file.puts ".c-page"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@fileList.each do |filename|

  File.open("templates/layouts/_partials/page-#{filename.to_s}.jade", 'w') do |file|
    file.puts ".c-page"
    file.puts "  img(src='images/pages/#{filename.to_s}.jpg', alt=''"
  end
end
```

`puts` adds a new line character so  I see no need for the first one and string interpolation will work better than appending with the `+` sign. Another note that I try and hold to is using `{}` syntax for single line and `do..end` for multi-line blocks. It makes it cleaner and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You need space between a string and a plus sign:

```
pry(main)> "  img(src='images/pages/"+ filename.to_s +".jpg', alt=''"
SyntaxError: unexpected unary+, expecting end-of-input
"  img(src='images/pages/"+ filename.to_s +".jpg', alt=''"
```

and this works:

```
pry(main)> "  img(src='images/pages/" + filename.to_s + ".jpg', alt=''"
=> "  img(src='images/pages/whatever.jpg', alt=''"
```

Or just use string interpolation, as engineersmnky suggested in the comment.

`"string"+` is treaten as running unary operator + on the string object.